# Include LESS Variables in CSS @import Directive

Tags: css, less

I would like to include a LESS variable inside the string content of my @import statement . . .

```
@my-font-name: Georgia;
@import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600|@{my-font-name}:400,300,700";
```

However, in the processed CSS, there is no transformation and it just looks the same:

```
@import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600|@{my-font-name}:400,300,700";
```

where I would prefer it to be processed like this:

```
@import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600|Georgia:400,300,700";
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm on the core team for less.js, variables in `@import` statements was introduced in . [Less.js v1.4.0-b1](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/dist/less-1.4.0-beta.js)

This should allow you to accomplish what you're looking to do:

```
@my-font-name: Georgia;
@import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600|@{my-font-name}:400,300,700";
```

Comment: Lol why would this get down-voted? I'm passing on info that we just released this feature. Silly SASS fans.

Comment: +1 worked great, but what if I add more than one google font? how would the syntax be?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot currently do this in Less, however it does look like the feature maybe coming soon.

More precisely its in less.js 1.4 alpha.

https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/410